# Take just the months in a series of dates in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series of dates that look like this:

```
0        8/1/2018
1        7/1/2018
2       11/1/2018
3        9/1/2018
4        9/1/2018
5        8/1/2018
6        9/1/2018
7        9/1/2018
8        8/1/2018
9        8/1/2018
10       9/1/2018
11       8/1/2018
12       8/1/2018
```

and so on. Note the data type of this is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. Now I want to just get a vector or list of the months as integers. I.e.

```
8 7 11 9 9 etc...
```

I am new to python, normally in C++ I would just do `std::stoi(it.first.substr(0, it.first.find("/"))` assuming it.first is the dates stored as a string.

Comment: Try `.str.extract(r'(\d+)/').astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your series is named `s`. `pd.to_datetime(s).dt.month.tolist()`

Comment: Thanks, any idea why I get this error: ValueError: day is out of range for month for your code?

Comment: do you have some bad data in there? You could try `pd.to_datetime(s, errors=‘coerce’)`

Comment: I dont think so, let me try that

Comment: You could also pass the parameter `format` to `to_datetime` which tells the function how the date is written in the string. Otherwise it infers it from the data. Check out the docs for more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: and if you don't want the overhead of converting to a `datetime` you could just do: `s.str.split('/').str[0].astype(int).tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

Using `findall` in `pandas`

```
df[1].str.findall('\d+').str[0]
Out[193]: 
0      7
1     11
2      9
3      9
4      8
5      9
6      9
7      8
8      8
9      9
10     8
11     8
Name: 1, dtype: object

#df[1].str.findall('\d+').str[0].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
df[1].split('/')[0]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.